# Two variables in one foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, enums, console, playing-cards

I'm trying to print on the console standard deck of cards. So far this is my code and I'm stuck.

My question -- is there any way to use Suit enum in cardnumber foreach statement and basically to print card number/suit, card number/suit and so on. I know there are better ways to do this, but I'm curious is it possible to finish. Also any ideas how to print only 2's on one row, after that only 3s on row and so on?

Regards

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Print_a_Deck_of_52_Card   
{

public enum Suit
{
    Club = '\u2663',
    Diamond = '\u2666',
    Heart = '\u2665',
    Spades = '\u2660',
}

public enum CardNumber
{

    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    J = 11,
    Q = 12,
    K = 13,
    A = 14
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;

    foreach (Suit val1 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        foreach (CardNumber val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardNumber)))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if ((int)val > 10)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", val);
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", (int)val);

                }
            }

        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the iterator variable anywhere within the body of the `foreach` loop even if that that loop contains another loop:

```
foreach (Suit val1 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
{
    foreach (CardNumber val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardNumber)))
    {
        if ((int)val > 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1}", val, val1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1}", (int)val, val1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to rewrite this so that all the 2's will be printed at together, and then the 3's, and so on, just swap the loops:

```
foreach (CardNumber val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardNumber)))
{
    foreach (Suit val1 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
    {
        if ((int)val > 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1}", val, val1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1}", (int)val, val1);
        }
    }
}
```

And to write them in a row, you can use `Write` instead of inside the loop to keep each value together, then `WriteLine` outside the loop to separate that row from the next:

```
foreach (CardNumber val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardNumber)))
{
    foreach (Suit val1 in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
    {
        if ((int)val > 10)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} of {1}", val, val1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("{0} of {1}", (int)val, val1);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: So simple... It was bugging me in the last hour and I just couldn't figure it out. Maybe its good idea to take a break sometimes. Thanks a lot! Only one more question - its adding "of" on every line, I guess its built in feature when you use enum's. Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: @tslid ah no, that's just how I was writing it (I assumed you wanted something like `"2 of Spades"`). Just remove the 'of' from the format string in `Console.Write`.

Comment: Oh didnt noticed added of at all :) I thought typeoff was adding it somehow. I still have a lot to learn but thanks for fast reply!